# rake routes not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Strange issue I originally generated a scaffold for an object.

I mistyped it and called it Medium, instead I meant Media. I updated everything manually and most if it is fine.

Problem:
the routes are not correct.

My routes.rb now looks like

```
MediaLoader::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :media
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
end
```

However when I run rake route I get

```
     media GET    /media(.:format)          media#index
            POST   /media(.:format)          media#create
 new_medium GET    /media/new(.:format)      media#new
edit_medium GET    /media/:id/edit(.:format) media#edit
     medium GET    /media/:id(.:format)      media#show
            PUT    /media/:id(.:format)      media#update
            DELETE /media/:id(.:format)      media#destroy
    signout        /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
     signin        /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
```

**NOTICE new_medium**

Thoughts on why this is. I cannot find medium anywhere p.s I am using Rubymine running in editor dev server.

Comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: yup I have restarted my server and also tried adding and removing the route. But every time i add it back it still says new_medium etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bit of Rails magic, [the inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-singularize) singularizes `"media"` into `"medium"`, and is doing that automagically for you in the route helpers.

Comment: Thats Rails for you ;).